# alternating hat colors

Tags: logic, puzzle

The puzzle that I am posting here has already been answered by "Set Big O" on the following link
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11744/alternating-hat-colors

I understood his method but couldn't understand how he came up with the method or why his method gives the correct solution. Please help me in understanding why his method works.

Here is the puzzle :

"A prison warden offers his inmates a game for their freedom. He will secretly write a number on each of their foreheads, with no two foreheads having the same number. The inmates get to look around, seeing every other inmates' forehead, but not their own. They then go into separate rooms, and each place either a white or black hat on their own head. When they return, the prisoners are lined up in order of forehead number. They win if their hat colors now alternate white/black.

Once the game begins, the prisoners may not communicate, but beforehand, they may agree on a strategy. How can they guarantee victory?

This puzzle has a logical solution, there is no need for lateral thinking.

Added remarks: The numbers aren't necessarily integers, or positive, or interrelated at all (except they are all different). The numbers are the wardens choices, while the hat colors are the prisoners' choice. I got this from Rustan Leino's puzzle page."

Comment: You would have commented on his answer there instead of creating new question.

Comment: I did .."Carl" also commented asking for a further explanation and that too, 4 years ago but none was given .

Comment: Start with an ordered sequence and numbering and than do some switching of the assigned integers - you will find that each operation results an even numbered of switched order.

Comment: @Moti, can you please explain what you mean by, " you will find that each operation results in an even numbered of switched order".

Comment: Start with an ordered sequence and numbered 1 to n of the prisoners. To derive to a certain state of pairing you need a set of switching of positions - this can be counted and this is what the solution suggest. I did not follow it to the last details but the principal is clear - by watching the rest of the group you are deriving understanding of the chains and from this your relative position.